# Redirect all subdomains to main domain by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain, program-entry-point

I'm trying to redirect all sub-domains to the root domain. For example, my domain is *www.example.com*. When someone tries to connect to *notexists.example.com*, I want to redirect it to *www.example.com*.

Comment: Since `notexists.example.com` is not a valid domain it **cannot** be redirected to main domain using rewrite rules.

Comment: @anubhava Ah, You have not been introduced to the beautiful peice of technology that is wildcard A records

Comment: `web browser won't have an ip address to visit if no DNS records exist for that subdomain` This is what I meant here :)

Answer (score 0):

This is first going to be limited to dns.

If DNS is not first setup then the client's web browser won't have an ip address to visit if no DNS records exist for that subdomain, so you will have no way of contacting apache for it to implement a server side redirection.

What you need is a wilcard subdomain/record. This is in the form of an A record:

`*    14400    IN    A    1.1.1.1`

You will access to the httpd.conf file (root access), if you are using cPanel without root access add * as a subdomain:
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9191/29/how-do-i-create-a-wildcard-subdomain-in-cpanel

If you do have access you will need to set up a virtual host - add the following to your httpd.conf file:

```
#
# Your VirtualHosts section
#

NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4


##
# this one accepts any subdomain
##
<VirtualHost 111.22.33.55>
    DocumentRoot /www/subdomain
    ServerName hostname.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/